# Problem in making a custom format for plain xetex

Tags: xetex, plain-tex, format-files, e-tex

I have lots of macros and so would like to create a format out of them.  I am using `xetex` as engine.  Suppose `format.ini` is a file which looks like this:

```
\input plain

[lots of macros]

\dump
```

If from the terminal I execute `xetex -ini format.ini` I get as error `Undefined control sequence \uselanguage`. The command `\uselanguage` is part of the macros after `\input plain`.
I think `\uselanguage` is part of the `etex` extension.  But I get the same error even if I type on the terminal `xetex -ini -etex format.ini`.

What should I do?

Comment: I think you should `\input etex.src`

Comment: Try `xetex -ini "*format.ini"` This should include the `etex` - extensions automatically

Comment: @egreg I changed for simplicity the file `format.ini` to `\input etex.src \dump`.  If I try `pdftex -ini -etex format.ini` all go well; but with `xetex -ini -etex format.ini` I get as error `UTF-8 Latvian hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-lv.tex
! Nonletter.
l.16 d4ž`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Also your method works with `pdftex` but not with `xetex`

Comment: @User: Well, I compiled a small document here with `xetex` but I don't have your document at hand, of course

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You don't need my document, because I get the error even without including my macros.  What have you typed exactly to output a format with `xetex` with `etex` extension?

Comment: @User: `xetex -ini -etex "*makeformat.tex"` (but perhaps, `-etex` isn't needed )

Comment: @ChristianHupfer And what's the content of the file `makeformat.tex`?

Comment: @User: Now we come to the content, right? `\input latex.ltx` and a dummy command `\newcommand{\foo}{This is foo}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If I use as `makeformat.tex` the file `\input latex.ltx \uselanguage{italian}` it compiles successfully.  But my macros are built on top of `plain.tex`, so I can't input `latex.ltx`.  If I change `makeformat.tex` to `\input plain \uselanguage{italian}` or `\input etex.src \uselanguage{italian}` I get some errors.  Do you know what should I do instead?

Comment: Well, `\uselanguage{italian}` doesn't work for me neither

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If you use `\input etex.src \uselanguage{italian}`, with `pdftex` works but with `xetex` doesn't.  And the problem remains even if I remove `\uselanguage{italian}`. (Thank's anyway for the help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`etex.src` loads babel's kernel via `bplain`, which includes the `\uselanguage` macro that was missing in the OP; but then, `bplain` calls `language.def` (not hyphen.cfg, as in LaTeX), which in your installation probably includes all the hyphenation patterns for languages that you don't actually use, like the latvian one. You should edit `language.def` to load only the hyphenation patterns that you need, and then create the format as specified in the comments: `xetex -ini -etex etex.src \dump`

Comment: Thank you, I will check your solution and then come back eventually accepting it.  But why, for example, the latvian hyphenation does not compile?  Why does it work with pdftex and not with xetex?

Comment: perhaps it is the encoding: if the latvian is in 8bit it should work in pdftex, but then it may be an invalid utf8 string.

Comment: It works, but the file is `language.def`, not `language.dat`.

Comment: As for plain formats, as stated in babel's documentation, I stand corrected.